# How to reach previously read emails by using Spring Integration?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, jakarta-mail

I am developing a dynamic and multiple IMAP channel listener application. For the purpose of effectiveness, I am not downloading the attachments inside mails, just getting the texts inside them. Also I am developing an endpoint to access that previously arrived mails and download & return that attachment in order not to download every attachment. So basically I am trying to download attachments only if there is a demand.

I am using ImapIdleChannelAdapter to listen mails inside integration flow. Here is my flow,

```
public ImapIdleChannelAdapter mailAdapter(ImapMailReceiver receiver) {
        ImapIdleChannelAdapter imapAdapter = new ImapIdleChannelAdapter(receiver);
        imapAdapter.setAutoStartup(true);
        return imapAdapter;
    }
```

```
public IntegrationFlow createMailFlow(GmailRecieverRequirements requirements, String clientID) {
        return IntegrationFlow.from(
                mailAdapter(gmailMailReceiver(requirements)))
                .handle(getMailHandler())
                .get();
    }
```

My question is, how can I access those previously read mails in different time? I know Java Mail has Folder - UID structure to access mails via UIDs. Here is the [link](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/UIDFolder.html#getMessageByUID-long-). However, I do not want to use javaMail inside my flow to save the UID. Is there any chance that I could reach UID of the mail inside the flow by Spring Integration? I am open to any other solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed low-level mail API functionality. Not sure what you mean with your `do not want to use javaMail inside my flow`, but we only can do that on demand fetching if we know the folder and message UID and with that respective API of the `IMAPFolder`:

```
/**
 * Get the Message corresponding to the given UID. If no such 
 * message exists, <code>null</code> is returned.
 *
 * @param uid   UID for the desired message
 * @return      the Message object. <code>null</code> is returned
 *          if no message corresponding to this UID is obtained.
 * @exception   MessagingException for failures
 */
public Message getMessageByUID(long uid) throws MessagingException;
```

The `ImapIdleChannelAdapter` can produce raw `jakarta.mail.Message` to let you to obtain its UID via `UIDFolder.getUID(Message message)` API.

Comment: Hi Artem, thanks for the response. So you are saying that inside my mailHandler I should reconnect the IMAP channel and get the UID of the message by javaMail right? While I was saying "do not want to use javaMail inside my flow" , I was trying to mean avoiding the reconnection to the IMAP channel via javamail.

Comment: I don't think it is possible without doing that. In our docs we have a sample how to move message from one folder to another: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/mail.html#mail-tx-sync. So, we indeed do there `message.getFolder()` and `open()`

Comment: Then, I will just reconnect the channel and get the UID and save it for later usage. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Well, you may consider to implement a `DefaultMailHeaderMapper` extension to extract that UID and store it in the header just when `ImapIdleChannelAdapter` does its stuff. this way you indeed won't have an extra step in your flow to reconnect and fetch this UID.

Comment: I have made a bit more research and figured out that there is a Message-ID header  key inside MimeMessage headers. It is not necessarily be unique always but mostly it is. I have saved that id inside my handler and used that to reach previously read mails by setting a searchTerm strategy. It works right now.